# cannot find match for supplied option in websphere

Tags: websphere

I have an EAR file which contains two war files, but I cannot deploy it in WebSphere.

How to define **mapmoduletoservers** ?

```
SpringApplication.ear
  -app_s.war
     - web-inf/web.xml
  -app_h.war
    - web-inf/web.xml
```

Comment: Can you rephrase as a question?

Comment: what is the error you get when deploying to WebSphere?

Comment: WASX7111E : Cannot find a match for supplied option

Comment: Just deploy it via web administrative console, or attach the script you are trying to use to deploy.